# How to integrate TinyMCE with WPForms

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I am trying to integrate TinyMCE with WPForms inside the WPForms Blog Post Submission plugin.

I inserted an HTML field with the code

```
   <script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/no-api-key/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
   <script>
       tinymce.init({
       selector: '#wpforms-421-field_7'
    });
```

This kind of works as TinyMCE is integrated but in a horrible layout. Also the Images that are uploaded using this are not actually reflected in the actual page.

[image]

How do I integrate TinyMCE with WPForms correctly so that Images can be inserted in the text area and saved in the submitted posts?

Answer (score 0):

You are asking a couple of different questions wrapped up in your request ... let me try to address each one:

**1 - TinyMCE looks odd in the rendered page**
The menus, toolbars, and statusbar of TinyMCE are part of the main web page that loads TinyMCE. As such if you are loading CSS onto the page that impacts these elements you can get to odd visual results like this.

I would use your browser's dev tools to sleuth out what CSS is impacting things.

**2 - How do I upload images using TinyMCE?**

You have not given us any details at all as to how you have tried to allow users to upload images via TinyMCE.  There is an insert image option that you can expose via the image plugin but it requires some back end coding to receive the image and process it.

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/image/#image_uploadtab
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/image/#file_picker_callback

One additional question on this - Wordpress already has a media library and a UI to interact with that while using TinyMCE to create content - why are you trying to do something outside of WP's own media library?

Comment: Thank you. My main problem is I have to allow blogs posts through the frontend from users who do not have to login to create posts. I believe this will not allow them to access WP media library this way.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the author want TinyMCE in place of the textarea when creating Form for submission of Blog Post using WPForm.

[image]
Image: Source: https://wpforms.com/how-to-allow-users-to-submit-blog-posts-on-your-wordpress-site/

The problem is WPForm does not come along with the TinyMCE especially for the post content. You will probably get SCRIPT error or UI problem. You can use different plugins other than WPForm. Else write some custom code particularly for the Post Submission Addon found with WPForm.

Answer (score 0):

You must to set Wpforms as "No styling" and check "Load Assets Globally"